# Calculate mean values of multiple measurements in a table with two categorical variables and a single continues variable

Tags: r, matrix

I have this puzzle to solve. 
This is given data

```
# A tibble: 351 x 3
# Groups:   expcode [?]
   expcode  rank distributpermm.3
     <chr> <int>            <dbl>
 1    ER02     1          892.325
 2    ER02     2          694.030
 3    ER02     3          917.110
 4    ER02     4          991.475
 5    ER02     5         1487.210
 6    ER02     6          892.325
 7    ER02     7          694.030
 8    ER02     8         1710.290
 9    ER02     9         1090.620
10    ER02    10         1288.915
# ... with 341 more rows
```

When I call table on this data like this:

```
table(ranktab$expcode, ranktab$rank)
```

I get a ordinary table:

```
       1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41
  ER02 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  ER03 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  ER04 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  1  1  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  ER05 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  1  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  ER07 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
  ER11 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  ER12 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  ER14 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  ER16 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  ER18 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  ER19 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  ER22 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  ER23 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  ER26 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

Now I would like to get a matrix looks like this table above, but instate of sum of cases I would like to have the valves of third variable in the data frame, if there are two observations, then the mean of these.

Comment: You need to elaborate. What exactly do you mean by "if there are two observations", is it in long format, in wide format? do you mean another column like for instance distributpermm.4, distributpermm.5 and so on?

Comment: Would you like to obtain the mean of <distributpermm.3> values referred to <ER02>, <ER03>, etc., or referred to the tuples <ER02, 1>, <ER02, 2>, etc.? I think the second one, it seems like the second column should be ignored, right?

Comment: Yes, @Patrik_P, the data is in long format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's consider that your initial data is in `df` dataframe

```r
df1 <- with(df, aggregate(distributpermm.3, by = list(expcode, rank), mean))
colnames(df1) <- colnames(df)

#this will give you final output in the desired format
xtabs(distributpermm.3 ~ expcode + rank, df1)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is what I am exactly searching, thank you very much.

Comment: Glad that it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to obtain the means of  variable relative to  variable, you can use `aggregate` function.

Try this:

```
expcode = c (rep ("ER02", 3), rep ("ER03", 4), "ER04", rep ("ER05", 2))
rank = c (1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 2)
ddistributpermml.3 = c (892.325, 694.030, 917.110, 991.475, 1487.210, 892.325, 694.030, 1710.290, 1090.620, 1288.915)

data = data.frame (expcode, rank, ddistributpermml)

res = aggregate (data [, 3], list (data$expcode), mean)
colnames (res) = c ("expcode", "mean (distributpermm.3)")

res

# > res
#      expcode            mean (distributpermm.3)
# 1    ER02                834.4883
# 2    ER03               1016.2600
# 3    ER04               1710.2900
# 4    ER05               1189.7675
```

If you want to keep  variable in some way, please clarify what you want to obtain.